# How to create a lightbox with a next and back button through one button/link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox

I am creating my own portfolio using HTML/CSS/Javascript etc.

What I want to do is have a button/link and when the user clicks that link, a light box appears.

With the lightbox, I want there to be a next and back button so the user can go through the content inside the lightbox. Maybe about 5.

I want something similar to this: http://www.designcouch.com/demos/responsive-css3-lightbox.html#
You click on one button and then able to click next.

I don't want something like this where you are able to click next and back but it shows 3 buttons on the page. I want one button/link/picture and the lightbox is able to navigate next and back: http://css-plus.com/examples/2011/02/css3-lightbox/

Not too sure if I'm making sense. I don't mind any programming language. A link or code would be great to help me!

Thank you

Comment: Why do you wanna reinvent the wheel when there's something already that exists?

Comment: Have you tried fancybox? http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ It's easy to implement and has exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/guviq/5/edit)**

You could do it in a very simple way:

```
<img alt="" src="images/thumb.jpg" data-gallery='[
    "images/1.jpg",
    "images/2.jpg",
    "images/3.jpg"
]'>
```

On thumbnail click we do:

- Open our responsive gallery overlay (with `background-size` set to `cover` in CSS)
- `JSON.parse` the thumbnail `data` attribute to get an array of images
- Count the number of images
- If there's more than 1 image >> show the prev/next`span` buttons
- Assign some `click()` function to our `SPAN` buttons >> to change the background image.
- Hide the gallery if one clicks outside of it.

Let's do first some styling:

```
#gal{
  display: none; /* jQ will make visible */
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999;
  top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;
  margin: 50px;
  background: no-repeat #444 none 50% / cover;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.9),  0 0 0 5000px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
#gal:after{
  pointer-events: none;
  content : "×";
  position: absolute;
  right: -30px;
  top: -40px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 3em;
}
#gal > span{
  display: none; /* jQ will make visible if >1 image*/
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: -25px;
}
#gal > span:nth-child(1){ left:0; }
#gal > span:nth-child(2){ right:0; }
```

...and finally apply our jQuery gallery logic:

```
var $call = $("[data-gallery]"),
    $gal = $('<div/>',{id:"gal", html:"<span/><span/>"}),
    $btn = $gal.find("span"), img, n, c, hov=0;

$('body').prepend($gal);

// SHOW GALLERY || CHANGE IMAGE
function galleryAnim() {
  $gal.stop().slideDown(300).css({backgroundImage: "url("+img[c]+")"});
}

// THUMBNAIL CLICK
$call.click(function() {
  img = JSON.parse(this.dataset.gallery); // Creates an Array of images
  n = img.length; // Get total images
  c = 0;          // Reset Counter
  $btn[n>1?"show":"hide"](); // show||hide prev/next btns
  galleryAnim();
});

// PREV NEXT BUTTONS
$btn.click(function() { 
  c = ($(this).index()>0 ? ++c : --c)<0 ? n-1 : c%n; // Loop Counter
  galleryAnim();
});

// HIDE GALLERY IF EXOCLICK
$gal.hover(function() { hov ^= 1; });
$(document).mousedown(function() {
  if (!hov) $gal.slideUp(300);
});
```

If you don't like to wait for every new image to load once you click "prev/next", to pre-load all the images, simply add after `n = img.length;` this code:

```
for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
  var _temp = new Image();
  _temp.src = img[i];
}
```